# How to find an app that blocks the screen saver or auto turns the display off?

Tags: display, sleep-wake, screensaver, screen-time

Yesterday, my MacBook was on the screen/display for 24 hours non-stop. Below is the "Screen Time" data.

[image]

I actually wanted to ask why it's happened, but after I asked here I tried to close AweSun app and then screen saver is showing again. AweSun is a remote assistant app like team viewer. Even no active screen/remote sharing the app will block my screen saver, and I don't see any sign or warning if the screen saver will not be showing.

So my question is how to find an app that blocks the screen saver or auto turns the display off? I just want to know if in the future there will be any application that blocks my screen saver again, as usually I have a lot of apps running at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook Pro Didn't Go to Sleep and did not ask for password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425324/macbook-pro-didnt-go-to-sleep-and-did-not-ask-for-password)

Comment: @Tetsujin sleep and screen saver are different things.

Comment: Sure they are, but did you have a look at the info Activity Monitor presented?

Comment: Yes, I regularly check the activity monitor app. So many running apps which prevent from sleep status yes but the screen saver and display off still showing

Comment: It's best if you include all information on what you have already tried. It saves duplicated effort.

Comment: Sorry, I never tried anything because I googled about this question, but I never found anything. I just found out about sleep instead of screensaver/display off.